# May's Alge' Top', Dependence on base point explanation

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory

[image]

Above is in [May's book](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/maybook.pdf) p7. I don't understand the last three sentences:

(i) From "**If the group happens to be Abelian...this is just [f]"** : $[b\cdot a ] , [(b\cdot a)^{-1}]$ are not necessarily elements of $\pi_1(X,x)$, so why does that imply $\gamma [ b \cdot a ] [f] = [f]?$.

(ii) From "... **$\gamma[a]$ is independent of the choice of path class [a]"**: Does this mean $\gamma[a] [f]= \gamma[b][f]$ for all $a:x \rightarrow y, b:x \rightarrow y$?

Maybe I am completely misinterpreting something... I need some elaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i)  He defines $b$ twice in two sentences; the one directly ahead of the one you're looking at says $b$ is a path from $y$ to $x$.  So $[b\cdot a]$ is a path from $x$ to $y$ to $x$, an element of $\pi_1(X, x)$.

(ii)Yes, that is correct.  If we think about $\gamma[a][f]$ represents, it means that you go from $y$ to $x$ along $a$ backwards, then loop around in $f$, then go back from $x$ to $y$ along $a$.  If you take a different path, along $b$, we want to see that doing $\gamma[a][f]$ and then $\gamma[b][f]^{-1}$ leaves you the same place.

The trip you take is backwards from $y$ to $x$ along $a$, then around $f$, then back to $y$ along $a$, then back to $x$ via $b$, then backwards around $f$, then back to $y$ along $b$.  But going around $a$ then backwards around $b$ is an element of $\pi_1(X, x)$, as is $f$; they commute.  So this is the same as going backward through $a$ then forward through $a$, then backward through $b$ then forward through $f$ then backward through $f$ then forward through $b$; this is obviously trivial.  So this is a more geometric/less symbol-pushing way to see that $\gamma[a][f]$ is independent of $a$.

Comment: Thanks, it is much clearer now. So I guess writing out what May meant would be: 
$\gamma[(a')^{-1}\cdot a] [f] = [f] \Rightarrow \gamma[(a')^{-1}] \gamma[a] = \gamma[c_{x}] $ where $c_{x}$ is constant path. Hence, as $\gamma[(a')^{-1}] = \gamma[a']^{-1}$, we have $\gamma[a] = \gamma[a']$. Is this right?